# Does internal potential energy affects temperature or only kinetic energy?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, molecular-structure

If I take an extreme case, where a body has only an internal potential energy with zero internal kinetic energy, does this body have a temperature? Another question related to it: if two objects A and B having different temperature: A: having only internal potential energy and B having only internal kinetic energy, can heat flow from A to B ?(temperature of A > B)

Comment: You know these cases aren't really possible?

Comment: yes I know. but I want to see if potential energy affects temperature and if potential energy can cause transfer of heat

Comment: Well, I guess **no** in both cases.

Comment: I believe you know the simple answer to both of your questions to be no. Though you should realize that heat tends to flow from the object with more kinetic energy to that of lower kinetic energy. So why would you think an object with no kinetic energy would transfer heat? It has none to transfer.

Comment: Ok but in general, internal potential energy does not affect temperature?